# Redirection in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm very new to nginx and hit the wall configuring simple redirection.
Here is my very simple config trying redirection:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    set $mobile "false";

    if ($http_user_agent ~* '(phone|droid)') {
        set $mobile "true";
    }

    if ($mobile = true) {
        return 301 http://X.X.X.X/mobile$request_uri;
    }

    location /mobile {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/video_m/video.sock;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/video/video.sock;
    }
}
```

When go to site from desktop everything is ok and my request is going to uwsgi.
But from mobile device I get an error from browser ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and request url looks like http://X.X.X.X/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile/mobile

There is obviously something essential and possibly very simple piece that I missing. Please help me out.

Comment: Try 'break;' in the if blocks - just below the set $mobile "true";

Comment: It didn’t work for me. I still get redirect loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a loop. The first time it hits the `if/return` a `/mobile` prefix is added. Then the URI is presented again and it hits the same statement adding another `/mobile` prefix, and this continues to be repeated.

To break the loop, you need to protect the `if/return` within a path that is not taken once the `/mobile` prefix is added the first time.

Maybe:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location /mobile {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/video_m/video.sock;
    }

    location / {
        if ($http_user_agent ~* '(phone|droid)') {
            return 301 $scheme://$host/mobile$request_uri;
        }

        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/video/video.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not know that after adding a prefix the request evaluates again from the beginning.